# zookeeper unable to open socket to localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:2181

Tags: apache, hbase, nutch, apache-zookeeper

I am using zookeeper ensemble for hbase. Zookeeper is running on 3 machines. While HBase is also in fully distributed mode. I have Nutch 2.x version. When I start nutch to crawl some data, it gives following buggs in nutch log file.

```
ERROR zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO - Unable to open socket to localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:2181
2015-01-23 16:34:21,956 WARN  zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Session 0x0 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
java.net.SocketException: Network is unreachable
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:457)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:449)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(SocketChannelImpl.java:647)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.registerAndConnect(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:266)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.connect(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:276)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.startConnect(ClientCnxn.java:958)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:993)
2015-01-23 16:34:22,063 WARN  zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper - Possibly transient ZooKeeper exception: org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /hbase/hbaseid
```

When I run a command on three zookeepers instances

```
echo ruok | nc 1.1.1.1 2181 it says imok
```

What is wrong with it? My hbase version is 0.94.14 and zookeeper version is 3.4.5 , solr version 4.10.3 ( for indexing )and Nutch version is 2.2.3

Comment: I have come to know that this error is because of zookeeper ensemble. But I could not solve it till now

Comment: Never used nutch but it seems it cannot locate the hbase.zookeeper.quorum. Do you have hbase-site.xml in your classpath with the proper zookeeper quorum (your zk hosts)?

Comment: If I create some table and insert some data in hbase, it works properly without any error but for nutch, above error are appeared

Answer (score 10, accepted):

( CentOS ) Check your /etc/hosts file and if it conatins like

```
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
```

change it to

```
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         ip6-localhost ip6-localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
```

Comment: It removes message "ERROR zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO - Unable to open socket to localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:2181" but second warning is still there and connection refused message also

Comment: The problem "WARN  zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Session 0x0 for server null" was due to wrong configuration of zookeeper server i.e port of all zookeeper servers should be same then this warning will be removed

Answer (score 3):

I don't know zookeeper, but the two IP addresses that you're posting don't have anything to do with each other:

`1.1.1.1` is an IPV4 address. `0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1` is an IPV6 address (and it's the one for localhost). The shorthand for the IPV6 localhost address is `::1`

Thus, if you're expecting a server on `localhost`, make sure that it binds to IPV6 as well and not only to `127.0.0.1` (which is the IPV4 address of localhost). I've seen problems like this with servers that only listened to 127.0.0.1, or with firewalls that only allowed access to localhost on IPV4, but not on IPV6.

I'm not sure what you expect to hit when you're going to 1.1.1.1. Are you using this address locally? AFAIK it's a publically routed address, but I guess it gets a lot of this kind of unsolicited traffic that it's more or less unusable.